# How to remove GNOME and GNOME on Xorg which shows up on login screen?

Tags: gnome, uninstall, 18.04, login-screen

Newbie here. On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gdm login screen, clicking the cog wheel below the password field shows the following options.

1. Cinnamon
2. Cinnamon (Software Rendering)
3. GNOME
4. GNOME on Xorg
5. Ubuntu
6. Ubuntu on Wayland

Recently, I messed things up by typing wrong commands in the terminal while trying to remove Xubuntu (I guess I removed ubuntu gnome desktop shell). I have completely removed Xubuntu now and the option 5. Ubuntu makes things normal as before. The options 3. and 4. were not present before.

How do I remove GNOME? I do not think that `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is the right way.

Comment: Same thing here With 18.04. instead of cinnamon I get: <<ol>>1. Gnome 2. Gnome on Xorg 3. LXQt desktop 4. Ubuntu 5. Ubunu on communitheme 6. Ubunu on communitheme on Xorg 7. Ubuntu on wayland <</ol>> Execpt LXQt (some kind of KDE flavor) they all login to the same desktop. I am currently using GNOME with communitheme  with Nemo (cinnamon as fie manger) the other (except LXQt) are irrelevant. How do I remove them/converge them into single login option? FYI [Comparison of X Window System desktop environments] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments)

Comment: @Roey I do not have the answer to your question. Why don't you ask a new question? As for my question, I managed to remove GNOME options sometime back but I have forgotten how I managed to do so.

Comment: Pontis We have the same problem. Multiple redundant desktop environments. I think my problem stems from the fact I upgraded from 17.10 where unity was still in use.

Answer (score 0):

**If all you want to do is to remove gnome then ignore the Step 2 and 7
and follow step 6 to if only a tty screen appears after restarting your computer.**

You may need an active internet connection before proceeding:

1. Memorise your username and setup a password if you don't have one.
2. Uninstall Cinnamon

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
3. Use the second answer to [Uninstall Gnome3](https://superuser.com/questions/422181/how-can-i-complete-remove-gnome-and-all-of-its-subprograms)
4. Restart
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
6. Enter your username and password
7. Reinstall gnome using

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3
   ```

Comment: however this removes cinnamon.  The question is asked in a way you would not suggest to purge cinnamon but gnome-session. And to install cinnamon instead. Also it would be possibly necessary tor remove nautilus as well to prevent two file managers installed. In the past this lead to bugs.

Comment: He actually don't ask how to remove cinnamon, but the `GNOME` record from welcome screen menu.

Comment: @Gryu I already referred to that in bold at the end of the answer but let me move it to the top then.

Comment: It is better to remove unnecessary for OP steps. Also, you could share answers by clicking a **share** link under answers, because of answers position could change *Use the second answer* could be deprecated soon.